# После обновления андроид что происходит с телефоном?

Tags: android, обновление

Что происходит с телефоном после обновления (по воздуху) версии android? Происходил ли сброс до заводских настроек и стираются ли данные (приложения и т.п.) установленные во внутренней памяти устройства? Или все остается как было до обновления?

P.S. Прошу прощения возможно задаю вопрос не в том месте, поэтому прошу не стебатся над этим.

Comment: При официальном обновлении по воздуху никаких изменений в установленых приложениях, настройках и тп. неприятностей не будет. Все останется, как было до обновления, это не перепрошивка, а обновление.

Comment: Возможны траблы, если Вы ковырялись в системе и переставляли данные своих приложений в директории системы, например, под рутом. Тогда они могут затереться, либо вообще обновление не пройдет, придется восстанавливать заводской образ (проверено на собственном опыте).

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, буду иметь в виду.